# NPM: How to add a "post-install" hook that's not run for package consumers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I'm writing an NPM module.

I'd like to automate some tasks after every `npm install` when developing the module locally.

However, I **do not** want these steps to be performed when consumers of my library perform an `npm install` and I **do not** want these steps to be performed after every `npm pack` and `npm publish` that I make during development (so this rules-out using the `prepublish` and `prepare` scripts).

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

(I've considered: (a) publish a separate `package.json` w/o the `install` script, (b) create a `./install.sh` in the project's root that users call instead of `npm install`... but this kinda sucks.)

Answer (score 2):

The `install:local` script here will run after `npm install` is run locally only (i.e. not when consumers install your package).

**package.json:**

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "case \"$npm_config_argv\" in *\"\\\"install\\\"\"*|*\"\\\"ci\\\"\"*) npm run install:local ;; esac",
    "install:local": "echo 'npm install' was run directly in the project, and not by a library consumer!",
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows.